# How can I add a column based on existing columns in H2OFrame in Scala

Tags: scala, h2o

How can I add a column based on existing columns in H2OFrame in Scala?

I want to add a new column which is the log of an existing column. how can i do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the original H2OFrame

```
val OriginalTable: H2OFrame = SomeDataFrame
```

convert original H2OFrame to DataFrame, add the column via sql function, make an implicit conversion back to H2OFrame

```
val NewTable: H2OFrame = createH2OSchemaRDD(OriginalTable).withColumn("newCol", log($"oldCol"))
```